# Printing image from JLabel (using Printer) using java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using java netbeans and want to print image from JLabel but its not working. If I use `TextArea.print()` its working. I just want to print image, please help.

```
Icon icon = noskha_kamilaa.getIcon();
BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics g=bi.createGraphics();
g.dispose();

try{ 
    printAll(g);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success");

}catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException  e)      // give an error
{       
    System.err.format("Cannot print %%n", e.getMessage());   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are disposing Graphics Object before printing

```
g.dispose();

try{ 
    printAll(g);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success");

}catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException  e)      // give an error
{       
    System.err.format("Cannot print %%n", e.getMessage());   
}
```

should be

```
try{ 
    printAll(g);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success");
    g.dispose();
}catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException  e)      // give an error
{       
    System.err.format("Cannot print %%n", e.getMessage());   
}
```

Comment: thank you  for your answer but 

catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException  e)  give me an error



exception PrinterException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: Sorry .. did not get you. what do you mean?

Comment: i did what you said but }catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException  e)  give me an error

Comment: can you tell me how can get image from label and print it ?? is there print fonction default lik textArea.print()

Comment: You can refer http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Printanimageout.htm

Comment: it work for textArea  by textArea.print() but in jlabel not work with Graphics